# How To save DataFrame Into Cassandra table using Spark Java API

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to save data frame into cassandra table using sparkJava API

I want to add the part of saving in the following code 
I want to save people dataframe into cassandra table and make queries on that cassandra table

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;

public class SimpleApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application");
    conf.setMaster("local");
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    SQLContext sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
    DataFrame people = sqlContext.read().json("/root/people.json");
    people.printSchema();
    people.registerTempTable("people");
    **//I want to save this TempTable or people dataframe into cassandra table and make teenagers SQL query on that cassandra table** 
    DataFrame teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19");
    teenagers.show();


 }
}
```

Comment: are you facing any error ??

Comment: I want to know the peice of code to save prople dataframe as cassandra table

Comment: you can use saveToCassandra method with the keyspace name, table name and a list of columns to save the dataframe
people.saveToCassandra("keySpace","table",Columns("abc", "xyz")

Comment: this error appears to me                                                                      cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method Columns(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
[ERROR] location: class SimpleApp

Comment: I am using sparkJavaAPI

Comment: df.save("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra",SaveMode.Overwrite,options = Map( "c_table" -> "test1", "keyspace" -> "abc_test")) . try this it should work

Comment: all these errors appears to me                                                                                                        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project simple-project: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /root/SparkJavaSimpleApp/src/main/java/SimpleApp.java:[49,93] ')' expected
[ERROR] /root/SparkJavaSimpleApp/src/main/java/SimpleApp.java:[49,96] ';' expected
[ERROR] /root/SparkJavaSimpleApp/src/main/java/SimpleApp.java:[49,105] illegal start of expression

Comment: Where and how we need to get cassandra connection , how to save oracleDF into cassandra ?

Comment: @NayanSharma when i say  oracle_mfDF.createOrReplaceTempView("M_FAMILY")
       val saveTc= spark.sql("select * from M_FAMILY where MODEL_FAMILY_ID > 2")   , saveTc doesnt have save method what should I do ?

Comment: @user3252097 check your maven/sbt dependencies please ideally it should come

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.12</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency><dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.0</version></dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
  
  

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-tags_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-preview</version>
</dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.nscala-time</groupId>
   <artifactId>nscala-time_2.11</artifactId>
   <version>2.12.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  
  </dependencies>

Comment: I have included all most all dependencies but no rescue